# Code Sign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.1'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

everything is correct, but does not work.

Code Sign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.1'

[image: http://imgur.com/a/wkwQZ]
[image]

This might be caused by ?

Comment: you check both project add target file  ?

Comment: I can't see the certificate expiration date in that screenshot.

Comment: @trojanfoe, it's a valid certificate, otherwise it wouldn't be a "Valid profile".
@ author, Can you give more details about your error ? Do you have any message ?

Comment: @MohamedAmine I'd still like to see it.

Comment: Just to the left of that screen you posted there is a white column with a `Projects` header and `Targets` header.  They each have individual build settings.  Click on all of your `Projects` and `Targets` and check that there is code signing attached to each one.

Comment: Did you make sure that a matching profile was located in the "Library --> Provisioning Profiles"

Comment: FWIW, you have "Don't Code Sign" in "Release" row.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot to show what the drop down menu looks like when you press the double arrows by "Debug - Any iOS SDK"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to test the app on your device, check everything in that box to code sign with your developer identity. If you're submitting for distribution, then check everything to sign with your distribution profile. If that doesn't do the trick, go into your organizer (Shift + Command + 2), click "provisioning profiles" from the pane in the top left, and make sure that your provisioning profile is in there, and that it says "valid profile" to the right of it. Let me know if you have any questions in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the organizer profiles and the profiles you can choose on xcode to sign are messed up. Try to delete the profiles on the organizer. Close xcode and download you profiles from developer.apple.com Then open directly by double-clicking the profile icon then try go to build settings and code sign with you recently downloaded profiles.

Good Luck.